# How to pass database connection to Kettle job from java

Tags: java, pentaho

I have one Kettle job which will get data from database X and copy the data to another database Y.

I have used some Kettle jars to run this job from java  and its working fine.

Now, my requirement is, how can i pass Database name to job from java dynamically?

Example:

```
String filename = "myJob.kjb";
KettleEnvironment.init();
JobMeta jobMeta = new JobMeta(filename, null);
jobMeta.setParameterValue("TEST_DB", "MyDatabase");
jobMeta.setInternalKettleVariables();
Job job = new Job(null, jobMeta);
job.start();
job.waitUntilFinished();
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try  jobMeta.activateParameters()  ?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that `jobMeta.activateParameters()` doesn't seems to work, what all is required to pass connection dynamically, however job step does not pick the parametrized name as follows:

```
<connection>${kettle.db.connection.name}</connection>
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to pass db name dynamically use generic connection pass all db connection properties dynamically to kettle job.